# Initialize PostgreSQL database with one .sql file

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I need to write an .sql file to init my whole PostgreSQL database.

I need to create a user, his password, import values etc...

I exported my database from PgAdmin, but I need to create the user, and to make all tables belong to the user, etc...

Basically, I want to run a single command on my terminal on any machine with the .sql file and be able to connect using my node.js server.

Here is my nodejs connection :

```
const pool = new Pool({
    user: "pepe",
    host: "localhost",
    database: "pepepizza",
    password: "pepe",
    port: 5432,
});
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to dump database

`sudo -u postgres pg_dump DATABASE_NAME > dump.sql`

but if you want to dump a table from database

`sudo -u postgres pg_dump -t TABLE_NAME DATABASE_NAME > db.sql`

i try this command on ubuntu and on the windows is like this command but pg_dump in directory that you installed postgres for example C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14

Comment: @0xRyN
Was your question solved with my answer?